Extending Connections from $TM$ to $T^{(k,l)}TM$.
I'm having trouble filling in the gaps of a proof in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds. $\def\nablax{\nabla_\bX}
\def\nablay{\nabla_\bY}
\def\nablaxy{\nabla_\bX\bY}
\def\nablayx{\nabla_\bY\bX}
\def\w{\omega}
\def\bX{X}
\def\bY{Y}$

Proposition 4.15 Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $\nabla$ be a connection in $TM$. Then $\nabla$ uniquely determines a connection in each tensor bundle $T^{(k,l)}TM$, also denoted by $\nabla$, such that the following four conditions are satisfied.

In $T^{(1,0)}TM = TM$, $\nabla$ agrees with the given connection.
In $T^{(0,0)}TM = M \times \mathbb{R}$, $\nabla$ is given by ordinary differentiation of functions:
$$
\nabla_X f = Xf.
$$
$\nabla$ obeys the following product rule with respect to tensor products:
$$
\nabla_X (F \otimes G) = (\nabla_X F) \otimes G + F \otimes (\nabla_X G).
$$
$\nabla$ commutes with all contractions: if ''$\text{tr}$'' denotes a trace on any pair of indices, one covariant and one contravariant, then
$$
\nabla_X (\text{tr} \, F) = \text{tr} (\nabla_X F).
$$

This connection also satisfies the following additional properties:
a) $\nabla$ obeys the following product rule with respect to the natural pairing between a covector field $\omega$ and a vector field $Y$:
$$
\nabla_X \langle \omega, Y \rangle = \langle \nabla_X \omega, Y \rangle + \langle \omega, \nabla_X Y \rangle.
$$
b) For all $F \in \Gamma(T^{(k,l)}TM)$, smooth 1-forms $\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k$, and smooth vector fields $Y_1, \dots, Y_l$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\nabla_X F)(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, Y_1, \dots, Y_l) & = X \left( F(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, Y_1, \dots, Y_l) \right)\\
& - \sum_{i=1}^k F(\omega^1, \dots, \nabla_X \omega^i, \dots, \omega^k, Y_1, \dots, Y_l)\\
& - \sum_{j=1}^l F(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, Y_1, \dots, \nabla_X Y_j, \dots, Y_l).
\end{split}
\tag{4.12}
\end{equation}

The part of the proof that concerns us is the following:

Proof: to prove existence we define $\nabla$ on $1$-forms by
$$\nablax \w (\bY) = \bX\left( \w(\bY)\right) - \w(\nablax \bY).$$
then we use (4.12) to define $\nabla$ on all other tensor bundles. The first thing that needs to be checked is that the resulting expression is multilinear over $C^\infty(M)$ each $\omega^i$ and $Y_j$, and therefore defines a smooth tensor field. This is done by inserting
$f\omega^i$ in place of $\omega$, or $f Y_j$ in place of $Y_j$ , and expanding the right-hand side, noting
that the two terms in which $f$ is differentiated cancel each other out.

I'm having trouble carrying this argument out. In particular, multiplying $\omega^1$ by $f$ and noting (using $\circ$ to denote where the argument of $\omega$ would go)
\begin{alignat*}{2}
F(\nablax(f\omega^1), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)
& = F(\bX(f\omega^1)(\circ) - \omega^1(\nablax(\circ)), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& = F(\bX(f\omega^1)(\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - F(f\omega^1(\nablax(\circ)), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& = F(\bX(f)(\omega^1\circ) + f\nablax(\omega^1\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - F(f\omega^1(\nablax(\circ)), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& = F(\bX(f)(\omega^1\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& + F(f\nablax(\omega^1\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - F(f\omega^1(\nablax(\circ)), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
\end{alignat*}
Then 4.12 gives
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(\nabla_X F)(f\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l) & = 
X \left( F(f\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l) \right)\\
& - F(\nablax (f\omega^1), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - \sum_{i>1}^k F(f\omega^1, \dots, \nablax \omega^i, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - \sum_{j=1}^l F(f\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \nabla_X \bY_j, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& = \bX \left( F(f\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l) \right)\\
& - F(\bX(f)(\omega^1\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - F(f\nablax(\omega^1\circ), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& + F(f\omega^1(\nablax(\circ)), \omega^2, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - \sum_{i>1}^k F(f\omega^1, \dots, \nabla_X \omega^i, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \bY_l)\\
& - \sum_{j=1}^l F(f\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \bY_1, \dots, \nabla_X \bY_j, \dots, \bY_l),
\end{alignat*}
but no cancellation seems easily recognizable :(

It is $\nabla_X(f\omega^1) = (Xf)\omega^1 + f\nabla_X\omega^1$. Further
$$X(F(f\omega^1,\omega^2,\dots,\omega^k,Y_1,\dots,Y_l)) = X(fF(\omega^1,\omega^2,\dots,\omega^k,Y_1,\dots,Y_l)) = fX(F(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k,Y_1,\dots,Y_l)) + (Xf)F(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k,Y_1,\dots,Y_l)$$
Then all cancels out by $C^\infty$-linearity of $F$.

Sorry, but could you better explain how it all cancels out?

Just replace in 4.12 with the things above and pull the $f$ and $Xf$ in the tensor $F$ out. Then you see that it cancels.
